# drop down navigation in notepad and brought into dw cs6 it working in live view not in any test browser and my pages aren't linked

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

This is my html and my css is after the html I'm building  a drop down 
  navigation. It works in live view but it doesn't work in any of the testing browsers
  and  my pages aren't linked. Why? can anybody help? Thank You...

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <title>index</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8".
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>

    <body>
    <nav>
        <div align="center">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="../index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="about us">AboutUs</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="policy">Policy</a></li>
                <li><a href="procedures">Procedures</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>

            <li><a href="websites">Websites</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="templates">Templates</a></li>
                <li><a href="customized">Customized</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="codes">Codes</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="html5">HTML5</a></li>
                <li><a href="css3">CSS3</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>            
            <li><a href="contact us">Contact Us</a></li>
          </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div align="center"><img src="simple_img_2.jpg" width="970" height="450"></div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

**Css:**

```
                    nav ul ul {
        display: none;
    }

        nav ul li:hover > ul {
            display: block;
        }

    nav ul {
        background: #efefef; 
        background: linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%, #bbbbbb 100%);  
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%, #bbbbbb 100%); 
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%,#bbbbbb 100%); 
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
        padding: 0 20px;
        border-radius: 10px;  
        list-style: none;
        position: relative;
        display: inline-table;
    }
        nav ul:after {
            content: ""; clear: both; display: block;
        }
    nav ul li {
        float: left;
    }



        nav ul li:hover {
            background: #4b545f;
            background: linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%, #5f6975 40%);
            background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%, #5f6975 40%);
            background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%,#5f6975 40%);
        }




            nav ul li:hover a {
                color: #fff;
            }




        nav ul li a {
            display: block; padding: 25px 40px;
            color: #757575; text-decoration: none;
        }



    nav ul ul {
        background: #5f6975; border-radius: 0px; padding: 0;
        position: absolute; top: 100%;
    }



        nav ul ul li {
            float: none; 
            border-top: 1px solid #6b727c;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #575f6a;
            position: relative;
        }




            nav ul ul li a {
                padding: 15px 40px;
                color: #fff;
            }   
                nav ul ul li a:hover {
                    background: #4b545f;
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  <div align="center">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="../index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="../aboutus.html">AboutUs</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="../policy.html">Policy</a></li>
            <li><a href="../procedures.html">Procedures</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li><a href="../websites.html">Websites</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="../templates.html">Templates</a></li>
            <li><a href="../customized.html">Customized</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="../codes.html">Codes</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="../html5.html">HTML5</a></li>
            <li><a href="../css3.html">CSS3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>            
        <li><a href="../contactus.html">Contact Us</a></li>
      </ul>
  </div>
```

I think you forgot the extension file of all links except index.html. It should be "policy.html" or somethings like that and it must exist (It means you already created those file).

Comment: I added .html and I added ../ to all my links. and exactly how you wrote your answer and my css only works in live view not on any testing browser and pages aren't linked. Thanks Ni Ngo. One question why my css not working in my browser?

Comment: I checked your code on http://jsfiddle.net/ and actually I saw it worked as well. Here is the result http://jsfiddle.net/4JgA4/121/. You can paste your code in the box on the left side and click Run. After that, you can see the result.